# django views count shows 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'comment_set'

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

'''
views.py,

I am learning django / python and I am stuck on an issue. shows some error like 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'comment_set', How cna i solve the problem. This is the code for view count.
'''

```
class PostDetail(FormMixin, DetailView):
    model = BlogSlider
    template_name = "blogdetails.html"
    form_class = CommentForm
    context_object_name = 'detail'


    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('blog-details', kwargs={
            'slug':self.object.slug
        })

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PostDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['commenting'] = self.object.comment_set.all()
        context['form'] = self.get_form()
        context['own'] = BlogSlider.objects.all().exclude(user=self.request.user)[:4]
        return context


    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        form = self.get_form()
        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
           return self.form_invalid(form)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        form.instance.post = self.get_object()
        form.save()
        return super(PostDetail, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_object(self):
        client = self.request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']
        ip = IP()
        print(client)
        print(IP)
        blogview = super(PostDetail, self).get_object()
        print(str(blogview.ip.all()))
        if client not in str(blogview.ip.all()):
            ip.ip_list = client
            ip.save()

            blogview.ip.add(ip)
            blogview.views_count += 1
            blogview.save()
            return blogview
```

Comment: Why did you inherit `FormMixin` class here?

Answer (score 0):

replace line

```
context['commenting'] = self.object.comment_set.all()
```

with

```
context['commenting'] = self.object.comment_set.all() if self.object else []
```

You are trying to read all the comments of even if the object is set to `None`